# "NS1" and "NS2" A records suddenly required?

Tags: dns, vps, nameserver

I have a VPS server that I host several sites on. One of the domain names I use for a site hosted on the VPS is registered through a different company.

The site was working fine until this morning when it randomly went down. 
After hours of talking to my hosting service support, they decided that the problem was I did not have an A record for `NS1` and `NS2` pointing to my name server's ip addresses and they claimed the absence of those `A records` are why the site went down.

I have never heard of needing an `A record` for `NS1` and `NS2` before.

I am confused as to why the site would work just fine without the `A records` and then suddenly go down when no DNS changes were previously made.

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: If you don't have `A` records for `NS1` and `NS2` then how are they expected to resolve? Presumably you are specifying the same nameservers on your other domains?

Comment: If you had no nameserver records it should never have worked, sounds like they are making excuses.

Comment: You were coasting on luck because someone else had DNS records pointing to your site. Then they noticed the extraneous garbage and fixed it. Your site died because your NS records were missing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your domain that went down is SomeRandomWebsite.com, where is the NS for that domain? ns1.MyAwesomeNameServer.com and ns2.MyAwesomeNameServer.com would be good examples.

Did the tech tell you that there were no A-records defined for ns1 & ns2 at MyAwesomeNameServer.com? Because the lack of those records would CERTAINLY cause your problem - if the nameservers cannot be found, then no one will know what the zone file entries are for SomeRandomWebsite.com.

If the tech told you that your website went down because there were no A-records defined for ns1.SomeRandomWebsite.com and ns2.SomeRandomWebsite.com, they misled you.

I am assuming that you have NOT configured ns1.SomeRandomWebsite.com and ns2.SomeRandomWebsite.com to actually be the nameservers for SomeRandomWebsite.com. Because that would be horrible :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the static public IP for your VPS right ? that is called as A record for the DNS

If your domain service company is not providing the DNS manager , Use any cloud DNS manager , get the NS from that DNS provider , Set those NS in your domain manager and your VPS IP as 'A' record in DNS manager